# ID tracking while swapping and sorting other two arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my (@data,$data,@data1,@diff,$diff,$tempS,$tempE, @ID,@Seq,@Start,@End, @data2);
#my $file=<>;
open(FILE, "< ./out.txt");
while (<FILE>){
        chomp $_;
    #next if ($line =~/Measurement count:/ or $line =~/^\s+/)  ;
        #push @data, [split ("\t", $line)] ;
    my @data = split('\t');


            push(@ID, $data[0]);
            push(@Seq, $data[1]);
            push(@Start, $data[2]);
            push(@End, $data[3]);                   

#        push @$data, [split ("\t", $line)] ;

}
close(FILE);
my %hash = map { my $key = "$ID[$_]"; $key => [ $Start[$_], $End[$_] ] } (0..$#ID);

for my $key (  %hash ) {
    print "Key: $key contains: ";
    for my $value ($hash{$key} ) {
        print " $hash{$key}[0] ";
    }
    print "\n";
}

for (my $j=0; $j <=$#Start ; $j++)
{
    if ($Start[$j] > $End[$j])
    {
        $tempS=$Start[$j];
        $Start[$j]=$End[$j];
        $End[$j]=$tempS;
    }
        print"$tempS\t$Start[$j]\t$End[$j]\n";

}
my @sortStart = sort { $a <=> $b } @Start;
my @sortEnd = sort { $a <=> $b } @End;

#open(OUT,">>./trial.txt");
for(my $i=1521;$i>=0;$i--)
{
    print "hey";
    my $diff = $sortStart[$i] - $sortStart[$i-1];
    print  "$ID[$i]\t$diff\n";
}
```

I have three arrays of same length, `ID` with IDs (string), `Start` and `End` with integer values (reading from a file).

I want to loop through all these arrays and also want to keep track of IDs. First am swapping elements in `Start` with `End` if Start > End, then I have to sort these two arrays for further application (as I am negating `Start[0]-Start[1]` for each item in that `Start`). While sorting, the Id values may change, and as my IDs are unique for each Start and `End` elements, how can I keep track of my IDs while sorting them?

Three arrays, `ID`, `Start` and `End`, are under my consideration.

Here is a small chunk of my input data:

```
DQ704383    191990066   191990037
DQ698580    191911184   191911214
DQ724878    191905507   191905532
DQ715191    191822657   191822686
DQ722467    191653368   191653339
DQ707634    191622552   191622581
DQ715636    191539187   191539157
DQ692360    191388765   191388796
DQ722377    191083572   191083599
DQ697520    189463214   189463185
DQ709562    187245165   187245192
DQ540163    182491372   182491400
DQ720940    180753033   180753060
DQ707760    178340696   178340726
DQ725442    178286164   178286134
DQ711885    178250090   178250119
DQ718075    171329314   171329344
DQ705091    171062479   171062503
```

The above ID, Start, End respectively. If Start > End i swapped them only between those two arrays. But after swapping the descending order may change, but i want them in descending order also their corresponding ID for negation as explained above.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: please ignore the hash creation there in my code.

Comment: Adding input data and expected output would be more helpful.

Comment: @Kanhu *Always* `use warnings`!

Comment: Thank You Biffen, but i prefer command line check for warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use different arrays, use a hash to keep the related pieces of information together.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use enum qw( START END );

my %hash;
while (<>) {
    my ($id, $start, $end) = split;
    $hash{$id} = [ $start < $end ? ($start, $end)
                                 : ($end, $start) ];
}

my @by_start = sort { $hash{$a}[START] <=> $hash{$b}[START] } keys %hash;
my @by_end   = sort { $hash{$a}[END]   <=> $hash{$b}[END]   } keys %hash;

use Test::More;
is_deeply(\@by_start, \@by_end, 'same');

done_testing();
```

Moreover, in the data sample you provided, the order of id's is the same regardless of by what you sort them.

Comment: Thank You, The data set i provided is according to the descending order of start and end, here you will find some start are greater than end and vice versa. So i want only starts smaller than its corresponding end value so i was swaping the two values if start > end for my next data processing step. Like after this , I wanted to negate the start of next data from its previous start point, but without sorting them i ll get only negative value at some points. So is the all process.

Comment: @Kanhu: Have you noticed my code swaps the starts and ends when needed, too?

Comment: yes, i noticed here. But I am not quite sure of the sorting procedure here in hash. As if it's gonna take care of my purpose of further processing! I am trying this, will update here. Thank You very much. :-)